# Hyperledger Composer on windows

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Please help!

Can I install Hyperledger Composer on windows?

I see in this link have install with Ubuntu and MacOS but have not windows.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs.html

Comment: Windows is currently not a supported platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to install a local version of composer on Windows directly. However, you may use virtual box and add ISO of ubuntu in it. This way, you can use hyperledger composer on your windows.

Comment: You may use Docker on windows for Hyperledger Fabric.

Read the prerequisites: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/dev-setup/devenv.html
Some extra-features for windows:http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#windows-extras

Answer (score 0):

I'm running composer with Docker Tools on Windows 7. I used the Fabric setup scripts provided here: https://github.com/acloudfan/HLF-Windows-Toolkit, but the Composer itself installs easily with npm install. No need to worry about sudo/not sudo. I just had to install Cygwin for running the fabric scripts (composer-cli runs on a normal Windows console).